# Post not shown in completed low-quality reviews of questions

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

I reviewed a couple of low-quality posts, and when I want back to get the question, all I get is the review status, not the post itself:

- https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/1029505:

  [image]
- https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/1029522:

  [image]

Answer posts still show fine. Same results in private browsing.